# is average of total and the sum of average of group distribution the same

Tags: python, sql, average, aggregation, weighted-average

I have a query that calculates the total sessions and total number of crashed sessions.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count,
  SUM(cast((CAST((session.platform = 1 AND session.iscrashed) OR
       (session.platform = 2 AND session.iscrashed) AS int)) as int)) total_crashed
FROM session
WHERE appid = '4ef36d'
 AND (CAST(session.uploadedon AS timestamp) >= timestamp '2023-02-07 00:00:00' AND
    CAST(session.uploadedon AS timestamp) <= timestamp '2023-03-07 23:59:59')
```

The total count here is `7896` and total crashed is `774`.
So the average is `774/7896` * `100` = `9.80%`

Now, grouping by month:

```
SELECT
   FORMAT_DATETIME(session.uploadedon,'MMM yyyy') session_uploaded_month,
count(1) as count,
SUM(cast((CAST((session.platform = 1 AND session.iscrashed) OR
       (session.platform = 2 AND session.iscrashed) AS int)) as int)) session_is_crashed
FROM hive.prod_views.session
WHERE appid = '4ef36d'
 AND (CAST(session.uploadedon AS timestamp) >= timestamp '2023-02-07 00:00:00' AND
    CAST(session.uploadedon AS timestamp) <= timestamp '2023-03-07 23:59:59')
GROUP BY FORMAT_DATETIME(session.uploadedon,'MMM yyyy')
```

The output is:

```
+----------------------+-----+------------------+
|session_uploaded_month|count|session_is_crashed|
+----------------------+-----+------------------+
|Feb 2023              |7227 |774               |
|Mar 2023              |669  |0                 |
+----------------------+-----+------------------+
```

This gives the total avg percentage of `774/7227 * 100` = `10.70%` for `Feb` only.

So my question being can a avg. percentage for group distribution be greater than the avg. total percentage?

Here total avg. is less than month avg.

Comment: Makes sense to me. This is like taking the average grade of the 5 smartest kids in your class vs. the entire class. Since all the crashes took place in February, you should expect it to have a higher average compared to the total.

Comment: Indeed. If you look at it from a mathematical perspective, an average is merely a fraction.  If you divide the same number (774) by a smaller denominator (7227) you get a larger result (than 774 / 7896).  In the end you're comparing apples to oranges (yearly vs monthly averages)

Comment: Look up Simpson's Paradox and that might help you see how this can be true